# make first uploaded gallery image as profile image

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I'm using Codeigniter, what I want to do is when user upload picture to gallery first uploaded picture should be selected as profile image.

my database structure

items table

```
|    id    |  slug  |  user_id  |  post_date |

|    12    |  test  |    111    |  12/5/2017 |
```

items Gallery

```
| gallery_id |  item_id  |     image     | 

|     121    |    12     |  profile.png  |   -- i want this record selected
|     122    |    12     |  gallery.png  |
```

i used this code it select random picture from gallery table.

```
    public function shopItems($id) {

    $this->db->select("*,MIN(item_gallery.gallery_id)");
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->join('item_gallery', 'items.id = item_gallery.item_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('items.user_id', $id);     
    $this->db->order_by('items.post_date', 'Desc');
    $this->db->group_by("item_gallery.item_id");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally Figured out the come up with solution thanks you guys for your help.

```
public function shopItems($id, $limit, $start) {

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');
    $expire = date('Y-m-d');
    $this->db->select("*,(SELECT image FROM item_gallery WHERE item_id = items.id ORDER BY gallery_id ASC LIMIT 1) AS profile_img");
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->join('item_gallery', 'items.id = item_gallery.item_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('items.exp_date >', $expire);
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where("items.status = 'yes'");
    $this->db->or_where("items.status = 'edit'");
    $this->db->group_end();
    $this->db->where('items.user_id', $id);
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->order_by('items.post_date', 'Desc');
    $this->db->group_by("item_gallery.item_id");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `item_gallery` table structure by adding and additional auto increment column.

```
| gallery_id |  item_id  |     image     | 

|     121    |    12     |  profile.png  |   -- i want this record selected
|     122    |    12     |  gallery.png  |
```

Now try the below snippet:

```
public function shopItems($id)
{

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $item_id = $query->row('id');

    $this->db->select("*,(SELECT image FROM item_gallery WHERE item_id = '$item_id' ORDER BY gallery_id ASC LIMIT 1) AS profile_img");
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->join('item_gallery', 'items.id = item_gallery.item_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('items.user_id', $id);     
    $this->db->order_by('items.post_date', 'Desc');
    $this->db->group_by("item_gallery.item_id");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Now the `shopItems` return the first image the user uploaded.

Comment: items cannot be limit to one bcz i have many items in the table while they are ordered by     $this->db->order_by('items.post_date', 'Desc');

Comment: How you will identify particular images is of a user? Means there is no `user_id` in `item_gallery` table.

Comment: user id from items table

Comment: items table linked with item_galley images are for items not for users, item table have user_id, its not user profile , items profile image

Comment: i changed this part but its shows same picture in all items

$this->db->select("*,(SELECT image FROM item_gallery WHERE item_id = item_gallery.item_id ORDER BY gallery_id DESC LIMIT 1) AS profileimage");

Comment: then you have to write one additional query to get `id` from items table. check out updated code.

Comment: make sure **ORDER BY** `auto_id` should be `ASC`

Comment: but for me its return different images. As I created db like you provided along with `auto_id`

Comment: shihas's codes look fine,@MahmudNaseem change your date format in unixtime...or change the format in order_by();[date to unixtime]

Comment: gallery_id  also auto increament, can we have two auto increment id in one table?

Comment: No you can't do it. If it is like that instead of `auto_id` use `gallery_id ` in **ORDER BY**.

Comment: i used your same code with gallery_id so i get all item with same image

Comment: that means every time `$id` value is same inside `shopItems `. Try to make sure about that.

Comment: items with same user_id have 3 items all three items have same images displayed while they have different image for its own

Comment: how to make it select its own pictures?

Comment: $this->db->join('item_gallery', 'items.id=(SELECT item_id FROM item_gallery WHERE item_gallery.item_id=' . $item . '  ORDER BY gallery_id ASC LIMIT 1)', 'left');  

can any one modify this code to fit

Answer (score 0):

Simply write query like this

```
public function shopItems($id) {
    $sql = "Select * from items a left join (Select item_id, image from items_galary group by item_id limit 1) b on a.id = b.item_id and a.id = '$id'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Try this

Comment: your code not works.  as it $this->db->limit(1); and my table have many items to show i want all the things from item table and image form itemgalley.

Comment: Please try this Query: Select * from items a left join (Select item_id, image from items_galary group by item_id limit 1) b on a.id = b.item.id

Comment: please edit the code and show me please..! on your answers

Comment: how to put others can you give it in active records way.

Comment: $this->db->join('item_gallery', 'items.id=(SELECT item_id FROM item_gallery WHERE item_gallery.item_id=' . $item . ' ORDER BY gallery_id ASC LIMIT 1)', 'left'); can any one modify this code to fit – this pulls all records